# how can I get Quagga.js working on android WebView?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, quaggajs

I am using quagga.js for barcode scanning and decoding it works perfectly in chrome and normal browsers. However it doesn't seem to want to work in an android webview app that displays the exact same webpage. Does anyone know why that could be?

I tried having the webview app ask for the user's camera permission on the first load up of the app but it doesn't want to give the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my manifest then added the code below that inside my webchromeclient.

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE"
>
> @Override
> public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
> final String[] requestedResources = request.getResources();
> for (String r : requestedResources) {
> if (r.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
> request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE});
> break;
> }
> }
> }